# JXL(Java) change to 1904 date system

Tags: java, excel, date, jxl

I need to change date system to [1904 calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) using [JXL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JXL_(API)) (rather than [1900 calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel)).

Everytime I write something in [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) using JXL API, date system is set to default and I need to change date system.

When I write negative time values (ex. -0:55) I get ################ instead of -0:55.

After I change in date system to 1904 in Excel ################ changes to -0:55.

Is there any way to change that automatically in JXL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual version of jxl can't do that. I have the same problem, and I just did some debugging of jxl. Jxl reads the record for the 1904 date format correctly, but it doesn't write it. It always writes the 1900 date format as a constant.

I see the following solutions:

1) Change the jxl library so it can write the 1904 date format. That should be not so difficult. In the method `WritableWorkbookImpl.write()` you have to change in the line

```
    NineteenFourRecord nf = new NineteenFourRecord(false);
```

the parameter value `false` to `true` for the 1904 date format.

In the private method `DateRecord.calculateValue(boolean)` you have to change the line

```
    value = utcDays + utcOffsetDays;
```

in a way replacing `utcOffsetDays` by a different constant with the number of days for four years less for the 1904 date format.

There might be more places to change (especially when doing a pretty solution with the 1904 format as a property of a workbook), but this is what's relevant for my program. Also pay attention for the obligations of the LGPL when selling your program.

2) Easier solution: Put always positive time values into the cells and store the sign in the cell format. Use for example the format `"[h]:mm:ss"` for positive values and `"-[h]:mm:ss"` for negative values.

Disadvantage of solution 2): Thought looking perfect, there *is* a positive value in the cell which is meant negative, and when doing calculations the results can be wrong.